# Welcome page background

Tags: html, css, background, size

I'm building a website, and I just have to make a welcoming page.
It's a simple page: just a background with a button, which directs to our homepage. I just have one problem with the background: my background is too big.
How can I edit with CSS and HTML so that my wallpaper fits all the screens?
(I want to make the page unscrollable.) All I have so far in the CSS:

```
body{
    background-image:url("voorpagina.jpg")

}
```

Thanks a lot!

P.S. I've already tried background-size:cover; but it didn't seem to work?

Comment: try `background-size:cover` for entire page and `background-size:100%` for screen

Comment: `background-size: cover;`  will work _as long as_ your `body` is 100% height of the viewport which it wont be by default. `html,body {min-height: 100% }` will probably fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I can see the image now, but I want to scale it, so that I get a non-scrollable page, and so that people see the whole image, (my image is too big, so everybody sees like 70% of the image). Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: It worked for me! Thanks everybody for replying!!

Answer (score 0):

`body{ 
    background: url("voorpagina.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}`

this should work if not you could use media-quires,

[similar to your question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720550/css-to-make-images-resize-and-fit-any-screen-the-same)

[similar to your question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262861/css-background-image-to-fit-width-height-should-auto-scale-in-proportion)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've already saw this on other sites and  I tried it too, but I don't know why it doesn't work for me:(. -o-background-size; doesn't seem to work?

Comment: on which browser are you testing? `max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto;` try this, it worked for me

Comment: Google chrome, I use Notepad ++ to edit the code, but I already fixed the problem! Thanks for your help though, I really appreciate it!:)