# Making html div take up full screen height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website based on a template. It uses bootstrap and can be seen here http://www.tombelina.com/fcrusade/

I am trying to get the first image to take up the whole screen on a mobile device screen. Currently it works perfectly for desktops but I can not get it to work with mobile devices.

Comment: Have you tried `height: 100vh;`?

Comment: it is currently taking up the whole screen on a mobile. Do you mean that the image should not be cropped?

Comment: you can try header  { background-position: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;}

Comment: I think it's because your gametracker image is so wide that it's jacking up the layout. It's wider than 100% of the page. Add the "img-responsive" class to that image.

Comment: @Aquinas can you add your comment as an answer. You were right it was the gametracker causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think it's because your gametracker image is so wide that it's
>   jacking up the layout. It's wider than 100% of the page. Add the
>   "img-responsive" class to that image - @aquinas

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@media` in CSS. Here is an example:

```
 @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   img.classname {
     float: left;
     width: 200px;
   }
 }
```

just change `classname` to any class and give it to the image.

**--OR--**

you can use this:

```
body {
    background: url('http://www.flywavez.com/images/sexy-girl-listening.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

ref: [CSS to make images resize and fit any screen the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720550/css-to-make-images-resize-and-fit-any-screen-the-same)

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your site, you should add some color to the background (Black would be suited i believe). And as for the image you should try this css code:

```
    [Image]{
height: 100vh; //which means the image will have the height of the screen. NOTE: Of the SCREEN and not the WEBPAGE.
}
```

You can do this and get the size of the image as of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @media

```
`@media (max-width: 767px){
   header .header-content{
      height: 550px;
   }
 }`
```

[Your site will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrl9Q.png)